# Copy last 3 char of text in one column to another column if cell is blank in excel spreadsheet with vba

Tags: excel, vba

```
If cell in Range("H1:H104000") is "" Then
    Range("H1:H104000) = LEFT(Range("D1:D104000), 3
End If
```

This is the code I am trying with no success.

Comment: Is that the exact code? As you can tell by the color formatting here, it's missing the end quotes on each range (and a closing parenthesis)  `Range("H1:H104000")= LEFT(Range("D1:D104000"), 3)` but don't you wannt to use `RIGHT` for the last 3 characters? `LEFT` will return the first – or "from the left side" – three. Also why not `If Range("H1:H104000") = "" Then` Or are you trying to check the entire range at once?

Comment: @ChristoferWeber - note that `If Range("H1:H104000") = "" Then` is an automatic type mismatch.

Comment: @BigBen Yes, I was writing as I was trying to figure out what was going on. My comment is a bit confused, as was I.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the Loop. You need to write the loop to iterate through the collection of cells, the code can't do it implicitly even if you compare a single range to a collection of ranges.

Also, to compare values use `=`. The `Is` operator is only used for Objects.

```vb
Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Range("H1:H104000").Cells
    If Cell.Value = "" Then
        Cell.Value = Right(Cell.Offset(0, -4).Value, 3)
    End If
Next
```

Once you're iterating through the column H. An easy way to refer to "column D in the current row" is by using `Offset`, which will return a cell, relative to your given starting position. In this case, we just need to move 4 columns to the left so I do `.Offset(0,-4)`

Comment: Helpful +:)  fyi you might c.f. my late post measuring time needed. - Side note: the `Select Case` statement knows `Is`, too; of course not as *operator* comparing objects, but as *keyword* together with comparison operators like e.g. `Case Is <100`.   @Toddleson

Answer (score 0):

You might consider

- assigning a *worksheet related* formula **evaluation** to a variant datafield array `data` and
- writing `data` back to the referenced column `H` instead of looping through the given range; this approach lasts only a *fraction of a second* while the loop through *each cell* by means of VBA needs several seconds:

```
Option Explicit                         ' head of code module

Sub ExampleCall()
    Dim t As Double: t = Timer          ' start timer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1                     ' << change to your project's sheet Code(Name) 
    Dim data As Variant                 ' provide for a 1-based 2-dim datafield array
    'assign worksheet related evaluation to data
    data = ws.Evaluate("=If(IsBlank(H2:H104000),Right(D2:D104000,3),H2:H104000)")
    'write to target   
    ws.Range("H2").Resize(UBound(data), 1).Value = data

    Debug.Print Format(Timer - t, "0.00 secs")    ' 0.20 secs   
End Sub
```

**Further note** A [worksheet related evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.evaluate) via `ws.Evaluate(...)` guarantees a *fully qualified range reference*, whereas `Evaluate(...)` would need more detailed range indications like `Sheet1!H2:H104000` or a further textual insertion of `ws.Range("H2:H104000").Address(External:=True)` to the formula string.