# how to calc 3*2*5+6 in a cell with out Equal

Tags: excel, vba

A function that can compute an expression such as (`2 * 5 + 6=16` or

`10*3*0.75=22.5`) without equating.

i did it with execl but it is not complate

[image]

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(G2170,FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(G2170),"C","*"))-1)*RIGHT(G2170,LEN(G2170)-FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(G2170),"C","*"))),IF(LEN(G2170)=10,LEFT(G2170,1)*MID(G2170,3,2)+MID(G2170,6,2)+MID(G2170,9,2),IF(LEN(G2170)=8,LEFT(G2170,1)*MID(G2170,3,3)+RIGHT(G2170,2),IF(LEN(G2170)=7,LEFT(G2170,1)*MID(G2170,3,2)+RIGHT(G2170,2),IF(LEN(G2170)=9,LEFT(G2170,2)*MID(G2170,4,1)*RIGHT(G2170,4),IF(LEN(G2170)=5,LEFT(G2170,1)*MID(G2170,3,1)*RIGHT(G2170,1)))))))
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/253353/excel-function-that-evaluates-a-string-as-if-it-were-a-formula

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471884/how-to-turn-a-string-formula-into-a-real-formula

Answer (score 6):

You can write an easy user defined function to evaluate those strings:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function EvaluateString(ByVal Formula As String)
    EvaluateString = Application.ThisCell.Parent.Evaluate(Formula)
End Function
```

The code needs to be in a *Module*.

It can be used as formula like `EvaluateString(A1)` and `A1` can be any formula that Excel is able to evaluate. If the formula includes other formulas like `SUM` that contain words they need to be the english formula version no matter which localization your Excel uses as `Evaluate` only handles english formulas.

And you probably need to make this function `Application.Volatile` if the formulas contain references to other cells. Avoid that if there are no references for sure. Volatile functions will have a high calculation impact on your sheets (the get calculated everytime anything gets calculated on the sheet).

Comment: FYI this uses the default `Application.Evaluate` which is fine if there are no cell references, but any cell references would always reference the ActiveSheet, so the result may be wrong when a different sheet is active.    Maybe `Application.ThisCell.Parent.Evaluate()` might be safer (to force the context to the sheet with the UDF)?

Comment: @TimWilliams Makes absolutely sense. I fixed the answer. Thank you.

Comment: ...true, indeed. C.f. post addition at [Further note to worksheet related evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69774503/copy-last-3-char-of-text-in-one-column-to-another-column-if-cell-is-blank-in-exc/69780932#69780932)