# Using Evaluate to multiply values in a range

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code to multiply the values in a range by 2:

```
input_rng = Evaluate(input_rng.Address & "*2")
```

What if the multiplier is stored in a variable instead? I tried replacing 2 with the variable name and it didn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: `input_rng = input_rng.Parent.Evaluate(input_rng.Address & "*" & variable)`

Comment: Fyi C.f. Notes to [Range.Evaluate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69774503/copy-last-3-char-of-text-in-one-column-to-another-column-if-cell-is-blank-in-exc/69780932#69780932) and [Help reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.evaluate) - @Johnnyg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Scott Craner's comment is spot on.  Here's a full example in case it is helpful:

```
Sub test()
    Dim input_rng As Range
    Set input_rng = ActiveCell
    Dim factor As Single
    factor = 2
    input_rng = Evaluate(input_rng.Address & "*" & factor)
End Sub
```

Comment: *Friendly hint* A worksheet related [evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.evaluate) - e.g. `Sheet1.Evaluate(myFormula)` - has the advantage that any internal range references are automatically fully qualified. @Gove