# Why do I get "error2023" in VBA when subsetting an array dynamically

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, subset

Problem: I want to use a subset of a VBA array using variables to steer the subset

My test program is

```
Sub test2()
    Dim MyArray() As Double
    Dim c As Double
    Dim d As Double
    
    ReDim MyArray(5, 2)
    
    c = 3
    d = 5
    
    MyArray(0, 0) = 1
    MyArray(1, 0) = 2
    MyArray(2, 0) = 3
    MyArray(3, 0) = 4
    MyArray(4, 0) = 5
    MyArray(0, 1) = 10
    MyArray(1, 1) = 20
    MyArray(2, 1) = 30
    MyArray(3, 1) = 40
    MyArray(4, 1) = 50
    
    a = Application.Average(Application.Index(MyArray, [ROW(3:5)], 2))
    
    b = Application.Average(Application.Index(MyArray, [ROW(c:d)], 2))
    

End Sub
```

I want to calc the average of cells 3-5 in row two. For the variable a the result is correct. Since I want to have the boundaries of the array defiend dynamically with two variables (c=3 and d=5) I tried to simply replace them. The result for variable b is "Error 2023" .

How can this be solved?

I already tried to use "" like (ROW("c":"d") or Row("c:d"). Result: only the Error type changes

Comment: Note that with `ReDim MyArray(5, 2)` you have declared an array of size `6x3`. You should have used `ReDim MyArray(4, 1)` or more safely `ReDim MyArray(0 To 4, 0 To 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
b = Application.Average(MyArray(c - 1, 1), MyArray(d - 1, 1))
```

But that's not convenient.
Try this:
Place at the top of the vba-page:

```
Option Base 1
```

Then you can use:

```
Sub test2()
Dim MyArray() As Double
Dim b as double, c As Integer, d As Integer
c = 3: d = 5
ReDim MyArray(5, 2)
MyArray(1, 1) = 1
MyArray(2, 1) = 2
MyArray(3, 1) = 3
MyArray(4, 1) = 4
MyArray(5, 1) = 5
MyArray(1, 2) = 10
MyArray(2, 2) = 20
MyArray(3, 2) = 30
MyArray(4, 2) = 40
MyArray(5, 2) = 50
b = Application.Average(MyArray(c, 2), MyArray(d, 2))
MsgBox b
End Sub
```

Comment: This calculates the average of two numbers. If you replace `MyArray(3, 2) = 30` with  `MyArray(3, 2) = 20` the result should be `36,6667` but it's `35` because it's considering only `20` and `50`.

Answer (score 1):

> Since I want to have the boundaries of the array defined dynamically with two **variables** (c=3 and d=5) I tried to simply replace them. The result for variable b is "Error 2023" . - How can this be solved?

To answer your question: the issue is that you cannot just use the tabular []-bracket evaluation by inserting VBA variables; use `Evaluate` by constructing the needed string input "ROW(3:5)" via `&` connectors:

```
b = Application.Average(Application.Index(MyArray, Evaluate("ROW(" & c & ":" & d & ")"), 2))
```

*Side note: don't forget to declare all needed variables and to have an `Option Explicit` set on top of your code modules.*

Comment: Fyi If you are referencing actual cell contents (not just row values) I'd prefer a [worksheet related evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.evaluate) - c.f. *Further note*  in question [Copy .. to another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69774503/copy-last-3-char-of-text-in-one-column-to-another-column-if-cell-is-blank-in-exc/69780932#69780932) @caz68

Answer (score 0):

@VBasic2008, you are right. @caz68, change the macro like this:

```
Sub test3()
Dim MyArray() As Double
Dim a As Integer, b As Double, c As Integer, d As Integer
c = 3: d = 5
ReDim MyArray(5, 2)
MyArray(1, 1) = 1
MyArray(2, 1) = 2
MyArray(3, 1) = 3
MyArray(4, 1) = 4
MyArray(5, 1) = 5
MyArray(1, 2) = 10
MyArray(2, 2) = 20
MyArray(3, 2) = 20
MyArray(4, 2) = 40
MyArray(5, 2) = 50
Sum = 0: a = c
Do Until a > d
Sum = Sum + Application.Sum(MyArray(a, 2))
a = a + 1
Loop
MsgBox "Average = " & Round(Sum / (d - c + 1), 2)
End Sub
```

Don't forget: Option Base 1 at the top of the vba-page!